# PYGAME: Continous K_DOWN doesn't really work

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

This code should make it so the black rectangle does continous movement while the K_LEFT or K_RIGHT are being pressed, but what happens instead is it just moves once it is pressed, and then once that happens, while the mouse is in motion over the window, it moves (when it shouldnt, it should only move when a key is being pressed). 
So here's the code, hopefully you can help:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit = False

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300
lead_x_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10

        lead_x += lead_x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x, lead_y,10,10])
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(30)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have indented all your code inside the event loop, meaning that you're only updating the screen and position of the rect when there are events in the event loop (such as moving the mouse, pressing a button, etc.).

Make sure you have your indention correct, like this:

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10

    # All code below was indented to much.
    lead_x += lead_x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x, lead_y, 10, 10])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(30)
```

Also, it is usually good practice to be consistent when you're naming your variables. Preferably, `gameDisplay`and `gameExit` could be named `game_display` and `game_exit` for more continuity.